# Hot-reload doesn't inject change on file change

Tags: javascript, browser-sync, eleventy

I have the following problem and have spent a lot of time trying to solve it without success. I have a folder that contains all the labels of my website in X languages. The problem is that when I make a change in that folder it is not updated in the browser, like you have when you change your layouts or content. What is strange is that when I update one file in that folder, I can see in the terminal that a change was made in the file, but when I check the `dist/*.html` file, I cannot see the new label in the `dist/**.html` it is not injected. I think it is a problem with `browser-sync`.

I tried playing with `addWatchTarget()` and `setBrowserSyncConfig({ files: [...] })` in `.eleventy.js` config file, but without success, the changes are still not injected.

Also, I found a working case. I update my translations file, then just save in `.elevently.js` to trigger the watch thingy. It will inject the new labels in the `dist/**.html`.

[Project with the issue](https://github.com/CallMeGrid/11ty-hot-reload-issue-example)

Here is my structure

```
i18n
-- index.js // custom script to pick the good label in the translations folder
src
-- _assets
-- _includes
-- content
-- translations
---- index.js
---- en
---- jp
.eleventy.js
...
```

```
.eleventy.js

const i18n = require('./i18n');
const translations = require('./src/translations');

module.exports = (config) => {

  // Custom i18n filter
  config.addFilter('i18n', (key, page, data) => {
    const pluginOptions = {
      translations,
      languages: LANGUAGES,
      defaultLanguage: DEFAULT_LANGUAGE,
    };

    return i18n(key,
      data,
      pluginOptions,
      page,
    );
  });


  // Needed to prevent eleventy from ignoring changes to our
  // template files since they are in our `.gitignore`
  config.setUseGitIgnore(false);

  config.addPassthroughCopy({
    'src/misc/favicon.png': 'favicon.png',
    'src/misc/robots.txt': 'robots.txt',
  });

  return {
    dir: {
      input: 'src',
      output: 'dist',
      includes: '_includes/partials',
      layouts: '_includes/layouts'
    }
  };
};
```

```
src/translations/index.js

module.exports = {
  hello: 'Hello',
}
```

Here are the logs when I save a change in the `src/translations/**/*.js` file. We can see Browsersync reloading before writing the change and then reloading after writing is complete. But the change is not injected into `dist/**.html`

```
[start:eleventy] File changed: src/translations/index.js
[start:eleventy] [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
[start:eleventy] Writing dist/index.html from ./src/content/home.liquid.
...
[start:eleventy] Copied 4 files / Wrote 68 files in 0.90 seconds (13.2ms each, v0.11.1)
[start:eleventy] Watching…
[start:eleventy] [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

And here are the logs when I save in .eleventy.js we can see some diff.

```
    [start:eleventy] File changed: .eleventy.js
    [start:eleventy] Writing dist/index.html from ./src/content/home.liquid.
    ...
    [start:eleventy] Copied 4 files / Wrote 68 files in 0.75 seconds (11.0ms each, v0.11.1)
    [start:eleventy] [Browsersync] Reloading Browsers...
```

Has anyone encountered this or has a workaround?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. You say the issue is in browser-sync. Are you saying that dist is always updated right, but the browser doesn't always reload or? It kinda feels like you are describing 2 issues here and I'd like to understand better.

Comment: I think the issue came from browser-sync or 11ty but not sure, because when I edit a translation file and save, the change has been detected so 11ty re-compile the files and browser-sync reload the browser. But the new label has not been injected in the dist/*.html, so it means 11ty has just re-compile the old version. But If I save in .eleventy.js it re-compile with the good change and when I check the dist/*.html I can see my new label.

Comment: Weird. And I assume if you use `eleventy` (not `--serve`) it reliably updates dist everytime, right?

Comment: @RaymondCamden exactly it will do a clean build. But it will lose the power of the hot reload, we will have to re-run `npm run start` to each change.

Comment: If you manually reload the browser, it works right?

Comment: @RaymondCamden no it does not works. I should have done this from the beginning here is an example of a project with the problem. I explained how to reproduce the issue in the readme https://github.com/CallMeGrid/11ty-hot-reload-issue-example

Comment: It's failing to run for me at all - looking for css.liquid.

Comment: @RaymondCamden sorry I fixed the error in the terminal

Comment: I can confirm it's working locally now - but I'm sorry - it's really hard to figure out the process here. I can confirm it's not hot reloading. Killing `npm run start` and rerunning it fixes it. Unfortunately I don't know enough about hot reload itself to tell you what's up.  Eleventy does see changes to the i18n files, but hot reload isn't firing. Sorry I can't help more.

Comment: Maybe start digging here? https://google.github.io/styleguide/htmlcssguide.html#Optional_Tags

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to look at the thing!  I will take a look to that guide

Answer (score 0):

Eleventy expects your partials to live in the `_includes` directory. If you move them there hot reloading should work as expected.

As far as I understand, this feature is designed for *template* partials, not *content* partials. I find it very strange that there is no way to break content into several files but as far as I know that's how it is...